# How can I check my transaction signature is correct?

Tags: transactions, lightning-network, signature, p2pkh, p2wsh

I have tried recreating the exact transaction from "Appendix B: Funding Transaction Test Vectors" from [BOLT 3](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/03-transactions.md#funding-transaction-output) from the Lightning RFCs. My transaction looks exactly the same when parsed, except my signature is different (since there is randomness involved in ecdsa signatures).

Is there a way to check that I have signed the transaction correctly? Thanks

Original tx:
0200000001adbb20ea41a8423ea937e76e8151636bf6093b70eaff942930d20576600521fd000000006b48304502210090587b6201e166ad6af0227d3036a9454223d49a1f11839c1a362184340ef0240220577f7cd5cca78719405cbf1de7414ac027f0239ef6e214c90fcaab0454d84b3b012103535b32d5eb0a6ed0982a0479bbadc9868d9836f6ba94dd5a63be16d875069184ffffffff028096980000000000220020c015c4a6be010e21657068fc2e6a9d02b27ebe4d490a25846f7237f104d1a3cd20256d29010000001600143ca33c2e4446f4a305f23c80df8ad1afdcf652f900000000

[My code on github](https://github.com/DariusParvin/bitcoin_tx_examples/blob/master/Funding_tx_testVec.py)

Recreated tx:
0200000001adbb20ea41a8423ea937e76e8151636bf6093b70eaff942930d20576600521fd000000006a47304402204650016c68a27f6fe28028de9f0cb1f939a6a27e7d4030c646263fb5374411aa022064d926c34b4fa5ae12b22437092f28f0bd806cc417a6725337282133726f643f012103535b32d5eb0a6ed0982a0479bbadc9868d9836f6ba94dd5a63be16d875069184ffffffff028096980000000000220020c015c4a6be010e21657068fc2e6a9d02b27ebe4d490a25846f7237f104d1a3cd20256d29010000001600143ca33c2e4446f4a305f23c80df8ad1afdcf652f900000000